# Python Regex String Extraction when the string is a number ranging from 0 to 9,999,999.99 and has either no commas or multiple commas

Tags: python, regex, list, dataframe, csv

Im looking for a way to extract this string our of this CSV list. Im thinking i need to change the , as they are giving me a issue but im not sure. the number at the end can rang from 0 to 9,999,999.00 and can have 0 commas or multiple

```
Transfer Out Pick - Total,EACH,42,552
```

CSV LIST:

```
    ['Actual Plan YOY Improvement,Main Processes Core Processes Line Items Unit Vol Hrs Rate Rate Hrs Δ to Plan (Hrs) % to Plan PY Volume (Base) PY Rate Hrs @ CY Rate Hrs @ PY Rate YOY %,Inbound Receive,Receive Dock,-,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Receive - Small,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Receive - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Receive - Large,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Receive - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Receive - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each To Bin - Small,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each To Bin - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each To Bin - Large,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each To Bin - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each To Bin - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Case Receive,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,LP Receive,Case,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pallet Receive,Pallet,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Receive Support,-,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Receive - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer In and Stow,Transfer In Decant,Case,16,412,248.45,66.06,52.84,310.6,62.14,125.01%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Transfer In - Small,EACH,94,933,283.93,334.36,252.63,375.78,91.85,132.35%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Transfer In - Medium,EACH,108,015,643.24,167.92,122.31,883.12,239.88,137.29%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Transfer In - Large,EACH,952,8.18,116.35,107.17,8.88,0.7,108.57%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Transfer In - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,196.02,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Transfer In - Total,EACH,203,900,935.35,217.99,160.83,1,267.79,332.43,135.54%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Case Transfer In,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pallet Transfer In,Pallet,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer 
In Support,-,203,900,160.17,1,273.01,1,138.5,179.1,18.92,111.81%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer In - Total,EACH,203,900,1,343.98,151.71,116.02,1,757.48,413.5,130.77%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,IB Prep,Cubiscan,EACH,42,0.42,100,10,000,0,-0.42,1%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Sample Center,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep Recorder - Small,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep Recorder - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep Recorder - Large,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep Recorder - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep Recorder - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep Support,-,42,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Prep - Total,-,42,0.42,100,5,000,0.01,-0.41,2%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Stow to Prime,Each Stow To Prime - Small,EACH,3,727,16.47,226.32,202.68,18.39,1.92,111.66%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Stow To Prime - Medium,EACH,3,881,27.22,142.6,103.55,37.48,10.26,137.71%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Stow To Prime - Large,EACH,53,0.49,107.8,102.08,0.52,0.03,105.6%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Stow To Prime - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,183.89,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Each Stow to Prime - Total,EACH,7,661,44.18,173.42,135.86,56.39,12.21,127.64%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Case Stow to Prime,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pallet Stow to Prime,Pallet,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Stow to Prime Support,EACH,7,661,6.77,1,131.38,418.84,18.29,11.52,270.12%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Stow to Prime - Total,EACH,7,661,50.95,150.37,102.59,74.68,23.73,146.58%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RSR,Case Stow to Reserve,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Case Replenishment,CASE,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pallet Stow Reserve,Pallet,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pallet Replenishment,PALLET,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RSR Support,-,535,759,34.04,15,740.64,29,431.41,18.2,-15.83,53.48%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RSR - Total,-,535,759,34.04,15,740.64,29,431.41,18.2,-15.83,53.48%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,IB Lead/PA,IB Lead/PA,-,203,900,24.99,8,157.99,6,497.18,31.38,6.39,125.56%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,IB Defect,IB Problem Solve,-,203,900,146.27,1,394.04,1,127.9,180.78,34.51,123.6%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,TOTAL,IB Total,EACH,203,900,1,600.64,127.39,98.86,2,062.53,461.89,128.86%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,DA - Building to Building Transfer RC Stow,RC Case Stow,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Pallet Stow,Pallet,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Pick,RC Pick - Library,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Pick - Pallet Rack,Case,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Sort,RC Presort Cases,Case,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Sort - Small,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Sort - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Sort - Large,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Sort - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,RC Sort - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out Pick,Transfer Out Pick - Small,EACH,18,982,60.66,312.93,272.1,69.76,9.1,115%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out Pick - Medium,EACH,22,538,81.44,276.75,243.05,92.73,11.29,113.87%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out Pick - Large,EACH,32,0.16,198.62,272.68,0.12,-0.04,72.84%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out Pick - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,153.8,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out Pick - Total,EACH,42,552,142.26,292.09,255.53,162.61,20.35,114.31%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out,Transfer Out,EACH,41,336,183.96,224.7,375.5,110.08,-73.88,59.84%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer Out Dock,Transfer Out Dock,-,41,336,46.44,890.06,171.68,240.77,194.33,518.44%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,TO Lead/PA,TO Lead/PA,-,41,336,0,0,5,021.96,8.23,8.23,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,TO Defect,TO Problem Solve,-,41,336,0,0,25,053,679,767.17,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,TOTAL,DA Bldg to Bldg Transfer TOTAL,-,41,336,372.66,110.92,79.23,521.7,149.03,139.99%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Outbound Pick,Pick - Small,EACH,131,919,467.44,282.21,249.27,529.22,61.78,113.22%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pick - Medium,EACH,160,891,622.21,258.58,234.65,685.66,63.46,110.2%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pick - Large,EACH,1,157,4.96,233.48,222.62,5.2,0.24,104.88%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pick - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,574.79,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pick - Total,EACH,293,967,1,094.6,268.56,240.94,1,220.08,125.48,111.46%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pick Support,-,335,519,171.66,1,954.57,2,148.7,156.15,-15.51,90.97%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pick Total (Incl. Support),-,293,967,1,266.26,232.15,213.6,1,376.23,109.97,108.68%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Sort,Batch Sort - Small,EACH,0,0.09,0,1,034.13,0,-0.09,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Batch Sort - Medium,EACH,0,0.09,0,493.2,0,-0.09,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Batch Sort - Large,EACH,0,0.09,0,2,462.8,0,-0.09,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Batch Sort - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0.09,0,10,001.7,0,-0.09,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Batch Sort - Total,EACH,0,0.37,0,0,0,-0.37,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Flow Sort - Small,EACH,49,922,175.61,284.27,275.86,180.97,5.35,103.05%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Flow Sort - Medium,EACH,49,617,178.3,278.28,264.68,187.46,9.16,105.14%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Flow Sort - Large,EACH,242,0.71,341.78,251.69,0.96,0.25,135.79%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Flow Sort - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,480.35,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Flow Sort - Total,EACH,99,781,354.62,281.37,270.12,369.39,14.77,104.16%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Sort Support,-,99,781,11,9,071,4,845.63,20.59,9.59,187.2%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Sort - Total,EACH,99,781,365.99,272.63,255.86,389.98,23.99,106.56%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack,Chutings - Small,EACH,49,597,330.84,149.91,138.16,358.98,28.15,108.51%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Chutings - Medium,EACH,48,953,288.1,169.91,152.02,322.02,33.91,111.77%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Chutings - Large,EACH,243,1.95,124.46,142.61,1.7,-0.25,87.27%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Chutings - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,427.8,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Chuting - Total,EACH,98,793,620.89,159.11,144.71,682.7,61.81,109.96%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Auto Slam,Package,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack - Autobox,EACH,8,071,15.45,522.43,451.96,17.86,2.41,115.59%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack - Lev/Autofold,EACH,37,472,77.94,480.8,501.71,74.69,-3.25,95.83%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Singles - Small,EACH,18,384,150.38,122.25,84.04,218.75,68.38,145.47%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Singles - Medium,EACH,48,937,635.84,76.96,64.55,758.13,122.29,119.23%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Singles - Large,EACH,594,13.01,45.65,34.95,17,3.98,130.61%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Singles - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,277,913.74,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Singles - Total,EACH,67,915,799.23,84.98,68.33,993.87,194.65,124.35%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Multis - Small,EACH,32,037,195.01,164.28,135.14,237.07,42.05,121.56%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Multis - Medium,EACH,43,437,252.05,172.33,131.85,329.44,77.39,130.7%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Multis - Large,EACH,253,2.76,91.7,130.83,1.93,-0.83,70.09%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Multis - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,284.19,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Multis - Total,EACH,75,727,449.82,168.35,133.22,568.44,118.62,126.37%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack Support,-,290,523,443.55,654.99,771.17,376.73,-66.82,84.93%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Outbound Prep,Giftwrap,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Partner Prep,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Library Services,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Custom Packaging,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Pack and OB Prep Total,EACH,290,523,2,406.88,120.71,107.03,2,714.3,307.41,112.77%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,OB Lead/PA,OB Lead/PA,EACH,290,523,204.35,1,421.7,1,123.14,258.67,54.32,126.58%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,OB Defect,OB Problem Solve,EACH,290,523,202.71,1,433.23,1,082.81,268.3,65.6,132.36%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Ship,Ship Dock,EACH,290,523,1,135.86,255.77,257.79,1,126.98,-8.89,99.22%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,TOTAL,OB TOTAL,EACH,290,523,5,582.05,52.05,47.36,6,134.46,552.41,109.9%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Reverse Logistics C-Return,C-Returns Processed - Small,EACH,0,0,0,77.19,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Returns Processed - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,68.94,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Returns Processed - Large,EACH,0,0,0,32.36,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Returns Processed - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Processed - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Stow - Small,EACH,0,0,0,28.1,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Stow - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,21.39,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Stow - Large,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Stow - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Stow - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,C-Return Support,-,0,0,0,56.19,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Customer Returns - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return,V-Return Pick - Small,EACH,0,0,0,326,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pick - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,272.41,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pick - Large,EACH,0,0,0,191.31,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pick - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,179.99,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pick - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pack - Small,EACH,0,0,0,323.28,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pack - Medium,EACH,0,0,0,202.97,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pack - Large,EACH,0,0,0,173.68,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pack - Heavy/Bulky,EACH,0,0,0,32.86,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Pack - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,V-Return Support,-,0,0,0,447.92,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Vendor Returns - Total,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Warehouse Deals,WHD Grading,EACH,0,0,0,18.95,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,WHD Specialty Grading,EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,WHD Support,-,0,0,0,10.38,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Warehouse Deals - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,External Repairs,External Repair Prep,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,External Repair Support,-,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,External Repair - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Trade In,Trade In Grading,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Trade In Support,-,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Trade In - Total,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Kindle Diagnostics,Kindle Diagnostics,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,TOTAL,REVERSE LOGISTICS TOTAL,-,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,On-Demand On Demand,Print On Demand,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Disc On Demand,EACH,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Create Your Own Ring (CYOR),EACH,0,0,0,10,001.7,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Support Support,Admin/HR/IT,-,331,859,245.54,1,351.54,596.63,556.22,310.68,226.53%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,On Boarding,-,331,859,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,AR Support,-,331,859,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Non_FC_Controllable,-,331,859,111.52,2,975.66,12,438.49,26.68,-84.84,23.92%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,IC/QA/CS,-,535,759,476.69,1,123.93,925.49,578.89,102.21,121.44%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Facilities,-,331,859,135.91,2,441.82,2,765.49,120,-15.91,88.3%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transport AmTran,Amtran In,Package,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Amtran Sortation,Package,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Amtran Out,Package,0,0,0,10,000,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,  FC Summary FC Summary,Vendor Rec (incl. Stow+Prep+RSR),EACH,0,256.66,0,0,305.05,48.39,118.85%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer-In,EACH,203,900,1,343.98,151.71,116.02,1,757.48,413.5,130.77%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Total Inbound,EACH,203,900,1,600.64,127.39,98.86,2,062.53,461.89,128.86%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Outbound,EACH,290,523,5,582.05,52.05,47.36,6,134.46,552.41,109.9%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transfer-Out,EACH,41,336,372.66,110.92,79.23,521.7,149.03,139.99%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Reverse Logistics,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,On Demand,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Support,EACH,331,859,969.66,342.24,258.9,1,281.79,312.13,132.19%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transport,Package,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,THROUGHPUT,EACH,535,759,8,525.01,62.85,53.57,10,000.48,1,475.47,117.31%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,  RC Summary RC Summary,Inbound,EACH,203,900,1,600.64,127.39,98.86,2,062.53,461.89,128.86%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,DA,EACH,41,336,372.66,110.92,79.23,521.7,149.03,139.99%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Reverse Logistics,EACH,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Support,EACH,41,336,858.13,48.17,32.93,1,255.11,396.98,146.26%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,Transport,Package,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%,0.0,0,0,0,0%,THROUGHPUT,EACH,245,236,2,831.44,86.61,63.87,3,839.34,1,007.9,135.6%,0.0,0,0,0,0%']
```

Comment: Do not use regex.  Instead use a CSV parser.

Comment: Why do you have all the fields in the same string, instead of splitting it by commas into separate fields?

Comment: Why is your entire CSV in a single element of the list? Where are the rows?

Comment: I appended a list with all cells of a table from a webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should help you. Try to get the name of the csv file, you can use Pandas Library for that. Then use the example below to get only numbers out of the string:

```
import re

txt = "126 7428,3453ssds"

numbers = re.findall('[0-9]', txt)

print(numbers)
```

Comment: i think i should edit the original question its not a csv file . Its a list i appened to be separated with comas there is no file.